# TreeView Leaf Node Not Remained Opened

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I Have Following Code to load a Treeview from DB Problem is That When I Click On Leaf Node It Collapse Into the Parent Node Any One Please tell me How can I set the Leaf Node To Be Remained Open
**update Code**
This My Complete code Through whic i am Populating my Treeview

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      fill_Tree2()
  End Sub
  Private Sub fill_Tree2()
      Dim PrSet As DataSet = PDataset("Select * from GPS_TREE_PROV")
      TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
      For Each dr As DataRow In PrSet.Tables(0).Rows
          Dim tnParent As New TreeNode()
          tnParent.Text = dr("Prov_name").ToString()
          tnParent.Value = dr("prov_id").ToString()
          tnParent.PopulateOnDemand = False
          tnParent.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand
          tnParent.Expand()
          tnParent.Selected = True
          tnParent.ToolTip = tnParent.Text
          'tnParent.CollapseAll()
          TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent)
          FillChild(tnParent, tnParent.Value)
      Next
  End Sub
  Public Sub FillChild(ByVal parent As TreeNode, ByVal ParentId As String)
      Dim ds As DataSet = PDataset("Select * from GPS_Tree_STA where Prov_ID =" & ParentId)
      parent.ChildNodes.Clear()
      Dim tnParent As New TreeNode()
      For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
          Dim child As New TreeNode()
          child.Text = dr("sta_name").ToString().Trim()
          child.Value = dr("sta_id").ToString().Trim()
          'If Not child.ChildNodes.Count = 0 Then
          '   child.PopulateOnDemand = False
          'End If
          child.ToolTip = child.Text
          'child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
          'child.CollapseAll()
          'child.Expand()
          parent.ChildNodes.Add(child)
          FillChild1(child, child.Value)
      Next dr
  End Sub
  Public Sub FillChild1(ByVal parent1 As TreeNode, ByVal ParentId1 As String)
      Dim ds As DataSet = PDataset("Select * from GPS_Tree_TEHS where STA_ID =" & ParentId1)
      parent1.ChildNodes.Clear()
      For Each dr1 As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
          Dim child1 As New TreeNode()
          child1.Text = dr1("tehs_name").ToString().Trim()
          child1.Value = dr1("tehs_id").ToString().Trim()
          'If Not child1.ChildNodes.Count = 0 Then
          '  child1.PopulateOnDemand = False
          '   child1.Expand()
          'End If
          child1.ToolTip = child1.Text
          child1.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
          child1.Expanded = True
          parent1.ChildNodes.Add(child1)
      Next
  End Sub
  Protected Function PDataset(ByVal Select_Statement As String) As DataSet
      Dim SqlCon As New OleDbConnection
      SqlCon = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
      Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Select_Statement, SqlCon)
      Dim ds As New DataSet()
      da.Fill(ds)
      Return ds
  End Function
```

Please Any One Tell me How can I set the Leaf Node as Remained Open When It Clicks On it through this code

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand the logic, since you didn't provide the code related to events, but from a glance to the code you should try to remove the line

```
child1.Collapse()
```

from procedure

```
FillChild1
```

Comment: I removed Also  child.Expand() But now the TreeView Expanded to Parent node and when I expand it an dclick on leaf node then it re collapse to Parent node and I Dnt know which leaf is Opened Currently

Comment: To try helping you I think I need to see more code, especially the one you associate to events.

Comment: I'm here and just noticed you are using Web controls :) Sorry I do not have enough knowledge about web stuff at the moment to help you.